# Question about TCP states for a webserver process - Why is it always on LISTENING state?

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I'm learning in-depth TCP now and I didn't understand the TCP lifecycle of a server process.
Supposed I'm running a web server on port 80, when I use netstat to view the connection, I see it listens on port 80, as it should be.
When new clients connects to my server, a new socket is created between the client and the server and the this socket is moving through the normal lifecycle (as described on the TCP RFC, or here http://www.sdsusa.com/connections/ ). this is perfectly understood considering TCP's demultiplexing abilities.

My question is: is the TCP connection that listens on port 80 follows the same lifecycle? I tried monitoring it but it stuck on LISTENING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listening socket always stays in "listening" state. When a new connection arrives, the listening socket is cloned, and the clone is put into "established" state and returned from the `accept()` call (or equivalent thereof). The original is left in listening state so that the application can poll it again for new connections.

Strictly speaking, the listening socket doesn't correspond to a "TCP connection" at all- it represents a *potential* TCP connection. Only the sockets returned from `accept()` represent real connections.

Comment: When the listening socket is cloned, it's put into the `SYN_RECEIVED` state.  It's not until the new socket later transitions to the `ESTABLISHED` state that it is returned from the `accept()` call.